# Can't find state inside Object.keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.myStateValue); // I see this on the console
    var test = configOptions ? 
    Object.keys(configOptions).map(function(key) {
        console.log('test'); // I see this on the console
        console.log(this.state.myStateValue);  // Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    }
    return() {...}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.keys(configOptions).map(function(key) {
    console.log('test'); 
    console.log(this.state.myStateValue); 
}.bind(this))
```

or better, if you have `ES6`:

```
Object.keys(configOptions).map((key) => {
    console.log('test');
    console.log(this.state.myStateValue); 
})
```

Comment: I just copied the OP's snippet. Presumably he just wants to test the visibility of `this.state` and will do more inside the loop at a later point.

Comment: @user1628461 That worked!! Thank you!! I think I need to learn more about this

Comment: @user1628461 oh yes you're right, my mistake.