# Access this inside Object.keys in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj
  }

  change() {
    Object.keys(this.obj).forEach(function(name, index) {
      alert(this.obj[name])
    })
  }

}

objct = {
  n1: 1,
  n2: 2
}

var test = new Test(objct)
test.change()
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined

I believe it means that `this` is undefined inside the object keys function. How can I access `this.obj` inside the Object keys and forloop?

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291845/cant-find-state-inside-object-keys), I can use `map`, but I need the property name and the array `index` inside the forloop as well. And here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisalup/0sbxfhwL/13/) of the code, if it may help you. Thank you!!!

Comment: try changing this function:
function (name, index) {
    alert(this.obj[name])
  })
into an arrow function to get 'this' context

Comment: Just don't use `forEach`. Use `for … in` or `for … of`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the function-context (the `this`) of the function you're passing into `forEach()` is now `window` and it's no longer your `Test` instance.

If you'll use an *arrow-function* instead, you'll be able to preserve the *lexical-scope* and your `this` would point to the current (`Test`) instance:

```
Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((name, index) =>
{
    alert(this.obj[name])
});
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Actually it's `undefined`, not `window`.

Answer (score 5):

`this` refers to the current context of the function and hence in your example `this.obj` looks for `obj` in the context of `forEach` callback. You can solve this by keeping a reference to current context i.e. `this` OR use an arrow function instead.

**OLD WAY**: In this solution, we keep a reference to the current context in variable `self`

```js
class Test {
  constructor(obj){
    this.obj = obj
  }

  change() {
    var self = this
    Object.keys(this.obj).forEach(function (name, index) {
    alert(self.obj[name])
  })
  }

}

objct = {
  n1: 1,
  n2: 2
}

var test = new Test(objct)
test.change()
```

**Preferred or Shorthand Solution**: By using Arrow Functions

```js
class Test {
  constructor(obj){
    this.obj = obj
  }

  change() {
  Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((name, index) => {
    alert(this.obj[name])
  })
  }

}

objct = {
        n1: 1,
      n2:2
}

var test = new Test(objct)
test.change()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was interesting to know about self, having not used it before. JS is changing fast :)

Answer (score 4):

A classic scope lesson in Javascript.

There are two ways to do this:

Using `bind()` which binds the scope of your forEach to the parent function

```
change() {
  Object.keys(this.obj).forEach(function(name, index) {
    alert(this.obj[name])
  }.bind(this))
  }
```

using `=>` which is another way of binding the scope of your forEach to the parent function

```
change() {
  Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((name, index) => {
    alert(this.obj[name])
  })
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. bind looks like a workaround when working with older browser compatibility :) (yes, i dont like babel)

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous functions are not bound to the context, so they doesn't have access to `this`; But the arrow functions are. So use that instead.

```js
class Test {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj
  }

  change() {
    Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((name, index) => {
      alert(this.obj[name])
    })
  }

}

objct = {
  n1: 1,
  n2: 2
}

var test = new Test(objct)
test.change()
```